# How to give each element in array an unique id if array consists of duplicats?

Tags: javascript

I have an JSON file with an array of 8 objects.

I need to turn it into array with 16 objects, where each object repeats twice and give each of these objects an individual id

I managed to duble number of elements like this

```
let d = data.reduce(function (res, current) {
        return res.concat([current, current]);
    }, []);
```

Then I tried adding `ids` like so

```
d.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.id = index;
    })
```

And I'm not sure why but all duplicates get the same `id`

Structure of JSON object

```
[
  {
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description"
  }
]
```

Code

```
export const fetchData = () => dispatch => {

    let d = data.reduce(function (res, current) {
        return res.concat([current, current]);
    }, []);

    d.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.id = index;
    });

    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: d
    });
  };
```

Comment: You are not cloning the object, you're just adding the object to the new array twice. Which means when `index` is 1, you're not changing the 2nd of 16 objects but still the 1st of 8.

Answer (score 0):

`current` is a reference object, you would need `Object.assign({}, current)` inside your array to make sure you get 2 copies of the original object, like so:

```
let d = data.reduce(function (res, current) {
    return res.concat([Object.assign({}, current), Object.assign({}, current)]);
}, []);
```

Or with the spread operator, like so

```
let d = data.reduce(function (res, current) {
    return res.concat([{...current}, {...current}]);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned, the issue if you are mutating the same object reference instead of creating new ones.

You can also move the ID assignment into reduce as well:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "description": "description2"
  }
]


const d = data.reduce((res, current) => [
  ...res,
  {
    ...current,
    id: res.length
  },
  {
    ...current,
    id: res.length + 1
  }],
[]);


console.log(d);
```